# SOAPHeaderElement

Tags: java, web-services, java-metro-framework

required help to write Java code to create SOAPHeaderElement or Element object for the following structure using JAX-WS 2.2.5 (Metro)

Metro provides WSBindingProvider to create header within Header  tag but, how to create a nested header is the question (putting user and password within Auth tag).

Any help would be appreciated.
    
    
    value
    value

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Create Auth class which have user and password as the attributes. Then add that auth object as the Header.